# WPF choosing an image via file dialog and interpolating it to a certain size

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to load up an image of my choosing in a WPF window and then change it's width and height. All I've come up with was:

```
public void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog.Multiselect = false;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Image files (*.png;*.jpeg)|*.png;*.jpeg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        ImageBox.Source= /*hard to miss lack of knowledge*/;
    }
}
```

but I'm not sure it's the right way to do it. For the interpolation part I've found the method:

```
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(ImageBox, BitmapScalingMode.HighQuality);
```

But the Microsoft docs didn't say anything about scaling it to a predefined height and width and I want to make it for example 200x200 if the given image is square.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [BitmapImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.110).aspx) and set its `DecodePixelWidth` or `DecodePixelHeight` property:

```
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    bitmap.BeginInit();
    bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName);
    bitmap.DecodePixelHeight = 200;
    bitmap.EndInit();

    ImageBox.Source = bitmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I change it's height and width based on it's original height and width?
`if (bitmap.PixelHeight==bitmap.PixelWidth)
{
    bitmap.DecodePixelHeight = 200;
    bitmap.DecodePixelWidth = 200;
    ImageBox.Source = bitmap;
}`

and so on for width<height and width>height?

Comment: If you need to know the original size beforehand, there is (afaik) no way around first loading a BitmapImage without DecodePixelWidth or -Height. Why do you need to know the original size at all? If you set either DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight, the bitmap's aspect ratio is kept.

Comment: So if it was 150x300 and I change only it's height to 200 it will be 100x200?